# android math to convert K to F temperature not working correctly

Tags: android, math

```
return (int)(((temperature -273.15) *1.8)+32);
```

Is my formula to convert kelvin to fahrenheit.  So it should be subtracting -273.15 from the kelvin value, multiplying that by 1.8, and then adding 32. However, rather than multiplying by 1.8, it seems to be multiplying the amount it subtracts by 1.8.  In other words, it's subtracting 491.67 instead of 237.15. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with a double instead of an int. Also, check if temperature is rightly passed here, maybe for some reasons you get temperature = 0 which would explain the error?

Answer (score 1):

cast to double not to int. 
data type double allow decimals.

Answer (score 0):

nevermind. The issue was actually that I need to convert F to Kelvin, not Kelvin to F. I thought my base number was coming from the weather API as Kelvin, but it defaults to F.